# Google Chrome 28.0 full screen API - does not respect CSS 'width:100%'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Up until Google Chrome 27.0 we were able to have a 640x480 image (from an IP Camera) on a page, and were able to use the JS full screen API to make that element go full screen using element.requestFullScreen("#myelement").

By setting 'height: 100%; width: auto;' in the CSS the image would stretch to fit 99% of screens beautifully. This worked in Google Chrome (before 28.0) and Mozilla Firefox.

Since Google Chrome 28.0, the full screen still works, but, 'height: 100%' will not stretch an image any more than it's native resolution. So if the image is 480 pixels high, it will not stretch any larger that that. It just centres the image with a black background.

So, we are trying to come up with a solution. We can manually stretch the picture by doing 'height: 1080px' which does then make it fit the screen. So I guess we could calculate the screen size using JS and then updater the width / height on the fly.

Is there any better solutions to this? And is it a bug or is it 'by design'?

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing the same effect in full-screen Chrome using the leaflet.js mapping library: a vertically-centered element with black above and below. This css hack did the trick for me:

```
.leaflet-container:-webkit-full-screen {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a div and full screen the div.

```
<div id="fsMe" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <img src="" alt="" style="height: 100%; width: auto;" />
</div>
```